# How to intercept special (alt / ctrl) key press?

Tags: python, curses

How can I catch key combinations like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in python `curses`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A terminal converts the control key in combination with a letter key to a normal ASCII code. This can be read from the [getch](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/wgetch.html)() function like any other key press.

```
CTRL-A: getch() returns 1
CTRL-B: getch() returns 2
...
CTRL-Z: getch() returns 26
```

Also, the [keypad](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_inopts.3.asp)() function must be called to enable other special function keys (e.g. left arrow, F1, home, etc).

I don't believe there is a portable way to receive meta-keys (e.g. ALT-H) through a terminal. Some send an escape (0x1B) followed by the modified key while others set the high-bit and only send one byte.